# Issue: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas

As I was trying to build a model using a random forest classifier algorithm with a timestamp column in my dataset where I have successfully converted my column into datetime format like timestamp   datetime64[ns] using to_datetime() method.
which is something look like this:

```
import pandas as pd


df= pd.read_csv("testData.csv")
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)

timestamp               temp            humidity        
2018-04-01 00:00:00     124.754612      42.189946
```

However, I am getting this error while solving my problem:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         1 # Fitting Random Forest Classification to the Training set
>         2 classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 42)
>   ----> 3 classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
>       247 
>       248         # Validate or convert input data
>   --> 249         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
>       250         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csc', ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
>       251         if sample_weight is not None:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       494             try:
>       495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
>   --> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
>       497             except ComplexWarning:
>       498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
>       536 
>       537     """
>   --> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>       539 
>       540
>
> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

What I am actually trying to do is to convert this “4/1/2018 0:00” to 2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z time format.

Comment: The `RandomForestClassifier` does not appear to take `Timestamp` features. What you could do is use an integer representation of your time from a certain starting point. For example: `time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())` (replacing `datetime.datetime.now()` with your `datetime.datetime` object.

Comment: thank you sim for your reply. can you show me some demo code because In my dataset, timestamp column contains this time( 4/1/2018 0:00 )format ? how can I convert this type into 2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z this format to achieve the goal????

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a minimal example (including a sample input of the type/shape that your code encounters and causes the issue)? With this it will be easier to help.